# Why didn't the Borg have/use cloak technology?

Tags: star-trek, borg

As we know the Borg have assimilated thousands of species. Still none of the Borg vessels seems to have or use cloak technology.

Cloak technology is not something that is THAT hard to develop. 
Checking the state of the superpowers in the Alpha Quadrant:

- Federation - don't have but just because of some treaty. They developed some successful prototypes however.
- Klingons - have it
- Romulans - have it
- Cardasians - don't have (no reasoning)

Even if none of the assimilated species had cloak technology - we know that the Borg assimilated at least some Romulan and Klingon ships. So they must have obtained enough from the technology to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: While the Cardassians don't appear to have home-grown cloaking technology, they did make use of Tal Shiar-provided Romulan cloaking devices on Obsidian Order-manufactured Cardassian _Keldon_-class starships in [DS9 Ep. 3x21: The Die is Cast](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Die_is_Cast_(episode)).

Comment: Because resistance is futile.

Comment: Perhaps Borg ships are too large to cloak.

Comment: @HighInBC this might apply for the cubes which are really huge. Still there are smaller Borg ships that can be safely cloaked as additional protection and tactical advantage. The Voyager managed to destroy a Borg probe and while being quite a versatile ship, it doesn't have the fire power of a Galaxy class ship.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Borg have cloaking tech. The Borg choose not to use it, as it’s inefficient, and ineffectual.

> Due to the enormous amount of power required to generate a cloaking field, there was, by and large, not enough power available to also power the weapons and shields. (TOS: "Balance of Terror") When the Romulan cloaking device was first installed on the USS Defiant, the ship even had to decloak to use the transporter. (DS9: "The Search, Part I") However, there were several times when advances in cloaking technology rendered these tactical inefficiencies untrue.

Federation ships are far below Borg ships in ability, yet are able to detect said races cloaked ships, every single time. Why then would the Borg who are so much more advanced use a piece of technology that is pointless to them. The Borg are looking for fights, species to assimilate. While these other races use inefficient cloaking fields, and it’s reasonable to assume the Borg could make it more efficient, again the need for cloaking is not there.

**TLDR**; The Borg’s primary goal is to assimilate any and everything that will improve their species. They do this by brute force; cloaking tech and subterfuge is something we have never seen the Borg employ.

Comment: I don't see anything inefficient in sneaking a probe with a few drones in Earth orbit, assimilating several people from Starfleet command and sending all their tactical knowledge back to the collective. Assimilating a single captain was much riskier and with less gains.

Comment: @vap78 the point is they have never cared to actually focus on the federation. they sent 1 cube, out of millions toward earth. if they cared to try they would over whelm the federation in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, they just don't need to. Their ships can be damaged, but regenerate back to 100% within only minutes. After that, they are completely immune to the weapons.

They probably just see it as a misallocation of resources. Why play hide and seek, when you can beat your opponent into submission sledge hammer style and take only minimal damage.

The federation only beat them back with incredible amounts of dumb luck. 
Now they may have wanted to use a cloaking device when species 8476 was beating them soundly.